# REST: How to support create-Or-Update and partial-update ? (aka PUT vs PATCH)

Tags: rest

We are designing WebAPI for our software for managing ecommerce product information. We want to provide (among many others) two operations:

1. Simple one: allow user to add/modify existing product information:

   - don't create new product if it not exists
   - don't delete any information from existing product which was not provided in this request

In my opinion HTTP PATCH method is proper way to handle this scenario (with json-patch or json-merge-ptach) with URL like this: /products/{ID}

2. Harder one: allow user to add/modify existing product or create one

   - create product if not exists in DB
   - don't delete any information from existing product which was not provided in this request (same behaviour as in first case)

I'm struggling with designing REST endpoint for this second use case. I have few options but none of them fits perfectly for me in the REST principles:

- a) Add custom HTTP header to the endpoint designed for first case (patch) to allow a caller to control of "not found behaviour" eg. create-entity-when-not-exists: true/false - but in my opinion PATCH shouldn't be used for creating resources.
- b) Design new endpoint using PUT with special header "preserve-not-provided-data" - this on the other hand violates for me PUT principles because PUT is create-or-replace not create-or-update method
- c) Create PATCH for /products URL (without {ID} at the end) - in this case we are updating whole collection(resource) of products - so if product exists we can update it or create new one if not exists.

For now c) solution looks fine for me with one exception: If in the future we would like to support batch operations (for both use cases: 1 and 2) we would like to use /products URL and it will conflict with URL from solution c)

What do you think ? Do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: As [Jim Webber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s) put it you don't "invoke" in REST, you just shuffle arround documents. The business rules triggered are just a side-effect of the document management. It's your job to design an application domain protocol which a client will follow, like a human does on ordering from Amazon or an other shop site. You should make use of forms (just look at the Web) that teach clients about the inputs a server expects and links to allow clients to progress through the application domain state machine a client will go through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PUT` and `PATCH` have differing message semantics, but the core context ("remote authoring") is the same.  In both cases, the client request is "Please, server, make your representation of this resource match my local copy".

For example, I `GET` a JSON document from the server.  I make local edits to it.  Now I want to "save" my changes on the server.  If the document is modest in size, I might just send the entire revised document over the network.  If the document is very large, and my changes are modest, then I might instead send the patch instead.

If you imagine using HTTP to publish edits of HTML web pages to a server, then you've got the right frame of reference.  There's not a lot of practical difference between "please patch the title of your copy of the document" and "here is a complete new copy of the document, with my edit to the title".  The bytes on disk are going to be the same in either case.

Given that, it would be very odd if those two methods for publishing a new revision of the document were to have vastly different side effects.

Your third approach, based on modifying `/products`, is potentially fine for both your individual and batch.  The server gets the new representation of `/products` (or the patch document describing the changes), decides whether to accept the changes, and if so computes what it needs to do to its own database to make things work.

Note:

> A PUT request applied to the target resource can have side effects on other resources.

The HTTP specification is relatively strict about what the message *means*, but offers the server a lot of leeway in how it behaves in response.